# Where is the operator precedence documented for the .NET Regex class?

Tags: .net, regex, operator-precedence

Where is the order of operator precedence documented for the .NET [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class?

I see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7h3k51c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but that's for JScript.

Also, it appears this is not affected by [`RegexOptions.ECMAScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but confirmation would be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to see the expression that confuses you?

Comment: The precedence is the same as that in the JScript link: unary operators bind tightest, then concatenation, then alternation. Brackets work as you'd expect.

Comment: @zerkms, I'm writing expressions, and I want to know when I need parens.  Porges, that's what I'm hoping, but I'd like to see it documented. If it isn't, I'll file a Connect bug.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: parentheses in regular expressions aren't used for changing operations/operators priority, but just to group the parts of expression. So - "I want to know when I need parens" - you need to use them when the syntax requires that.

Comment: @zerkms, I'm not sure what you mean by "operation priority".  However, non-capturing groups can certainly be used to change the overall precedence.  For instance, assuming anchors bind more strongly than alternation, it would make sense to use non-capturing groups around an alternation in the whole expression.  `^(?:this|that)$`

Comment: Obviously I need to use them when the syntax requires that.  Operator precedence is part of the syntax.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: could you please give any example of regular expression which demonstrates the issue (when precedence is not obvious or may vary on adding parentheses)

Comment: `^(?:this|that)$` === `^this|that$`, so parentheses here change nothing

Comment: @zerkms, no.  See [Ideone](http://ideone.com/odc8h).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: yep, my fault. But anyway - in this case parentheses is a **required** part of expression, just because that is how you *group* two substrings. And this has nothing to do with precedence

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen you say there are different flavors in REXEG. Thank you for sharing this link [Compare Regular Expression Flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Comment: I found only this documentation about [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This was asked a long time ago, but not answered.

The .Net regex operator precidence is defined at the bottom of the Regular Expression Syntax page [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: That doc link is actually for the VS 2010 JScript engine not the .NET engine. I've put the latest link and a copy of the table in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76442812/1882616).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the real answer is as simple as you'd like. The short (and incomplete) answer is simply "all expressions are evaluated left to right" ...

For the long answer go here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k.aspx

> The .NET Framework regular expression engine is a backtracking regular
>   expression matcher that incorporates a traditional Nondeterministic
>   Finite Automaton (NFA) engine ... traditional NFA engines perform
>   pattern matching, **their processing order is driven by the regular
>   expression pattern**. As it processes a particular language element,
>   the engine uses greedy matching; that is, it matches as much of the
>   input string as it possibly can. But it also saves its state after
>   successfully matching a subexpression. If a match eventually fails,
>   the engine can return to a saved state so it can try additional
>   matches.

**Edit: Forgot to answer the second part of your question.**

With regard to RegexOptions.ECMAScript, you can reference these docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

> The behavior of ECMAScript and canonical regular expressions differs
>   in three areas: character class syntax, self-referencing capturing
>   groups, and octal versus backreference interpretation.

It doesn't look like "order" is affected, but there could be other issues. The docs do a good job of illustrating the differences.

Comment: The processing order is different from the operator precedence order.  The processing order describes how it's executed (on each input) after it's parsed.  Operator precedence is a key part of how it's parsed.  I agree that "all expressions are evaluated left to right" is not a complete answer.  If it were, `^\d` would be a slash at the beginning of the string (^\\) followed by a literal `d`.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify [Donald Rich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42860714/1882616), Microsoft hasn't provide a documented order of precedence for the .NET Regex engine. However, they did document the precedence order for the old Visual Studio 2010 JScript engine, which seems to match how .NET behaves. I've duplicated it below in case the Microsoft docs disappear.

From [Regular Expression Syntax > Order of Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ae5bf541(v=vs.100)#order-of-precedence):

> A regular expression is evaluated much like an arithmetic expression; that is, it is evaluated from left to right and follows an order of precedence.
>
> The following table contains the order of precedence of the regular expression operators, from highest to lowest.
>
> | Operator or operators | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | \ | Escape |
> | (), (?:), (?=), [] | Parentheses and brackets |
> | *, +, ?, {n}, {n,}, {n,m} | Quantifiers |
> | ^, $, \anymetacharacter | Anchors and sequences |
> | | | Alternation |
>
> Characters have higher precedence than the alternation operator, which, for example, allows "m|food" to match "m" or "food".